# Unity's particle system creating background for sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

Okay, so I've been having some trouble with this. I tried to import my own sprite (just a basic triangle) into the Unity Particle System, and it's been making a white background on my previously transparent sprite. Here's a picture of my settings.

Comment: It looks like the image failed to attach, please edit your post and attach it so we can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Texture type of your sprite from the Inspector Window.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).